# Setting multiple custom email id in terraform for Azure lb scaling fails

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-load-balancer

We can set the admin email ids for scaling in vmss as mentioned in the below link.

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/monitor_autoscale_setting

but when a multiple email id's are specified

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktyz1.png)

```html
notification {
    email {
      send_to_subscription_administrator    = true
      send_to_subscription_co_administrator = true
      custom_emails                         = ["email@test.com;email2@test.com"]
    }
```

the terraform fails with the below error.

**[1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mError creating AutoScale Setting "VMSS-RG" (Resource Group "VMSS-RG"): insights.AutoscaleSettingsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=400 Code="NotificationEmailInvalidValue" Message="Notification email address 'email@test.com;email2@test.com' has an invalid value."[0m**

Any one faced this issue, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As per the Terraform documentation for the resource [azurerm_monitor_autoscale_setting](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/monitor_autoscale_setting#custom_emails), the custom_emails param accepts a list of email addresses. Please try configuring the resource in following way.

```
notification {
email {
  send_to_subscription_administrator    = true
  send_to_subscription_co_administrator = true
  custom_emails                         = ["email@test.com", "email2@test.com"]
}
```